# What documents needed for German marriage?

Tags: germany, marriage, documentation

My German partner and I are in the process of applying for permission to marry in Germany. We've gotten all the documents requested, but I have a question about one of the documents that the Standesamt requested: payslips for me for the last 3 months. They do not ask this from my partner, who is German, and I am a foreigner (American), who has been working here for 3 years.

I am paid by the Landesregierung, and they specifically say they only give you a new payslip when something changes, i.e. you get a bonus or move up a Stufe or your Konto changes, etc. As such, I have only one payslip from the last 3 months (which ironically is because it's precisely not my normal pay -- it was the 300 euro energy bonus that triggered the issuance of this one), and the other one is from 5 months ago (which is my normal pay because this was when I was bumped to Stufe 3). Of course, this caveat is printed on the document and the Landesregierung specifically answered my inquiry explaining that and not offering to issue me any extra payslips. Our contact in the Standesamt did not seem satisfied with the submitted documents and reiterated that she needs payslips from the last 3 months, even though I submitted what I have and explained the Landesregierung policy. As a precaution, I have printed my bank statement blanking out everything except my last three pay deposits.

I've been looking, and I can't see where this payslip requirement is actually a requirement to be issued a permission to marry. If the person in the Standesamt continues to give me a hard time about it, is there any recourse? Is this a real requirement to get married? Can unemployed immigrants really not get married in Germany? (granted, I'm employed and have been being paid, I'm just shocked if this were true as it seems like a violation of a basic human right.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which state?

- Baden Württemberg

Did you supply a US Marriage Certificate (Ehefähigkeitszeugnisse), i.e. proof that you are not married?

One thread **suggested** that if that is not possible, then an exception must be applied for at a court. The fee is based, in some states, on income.

> [Einkommensnachweis beim Standesamt Ausländerrecht](https://www.123recht.de/forum/auslaenderrecht/Einkommensnachweis-beim-Standesamt-__f577034.html)
> Aus diesem Grunde muss beim OLG eine Befreiung von der Pflicht, ein solches Zeugnis vorzulegen beantragt werden.
> Die Kosten dafür richten sich in manchen Bundesländern nach der Höhe des Einkommens. Und um das zu ermitteln, werden die Gehaltsnachweise gebraucht.
>
> > For this reason, an exemption from the obligation to submit such a certificate must be applied for at the Higher Regional Court.
> > In some federal states, the costs for this depend on the level of income.  And to determine that, the salary slips are needed.

I found a confirmation about the first statement, <strike>but nothing about the fee</strike>. See quote below, which states that if the net income cannot be reliably determined the highest amount will be taken (€305.00).

> [Ehefähigkeitszeugnis - Ausstellung beantragen - Serviceportal Baden-Württemberg](https://www.service-bw.de/zufi/leistungen/1822)
> Ausländer und Ausländerinnen, die in Deutschland heiraten möchten, brauchen auch ein Ehefähigkeitszeugnis.
> In diesem Zeugnis bestätigt die zuständige Heimatbehörde, dass der Eheschließung kein gesetzliches Ehehindernis entgegensteht.
> **Ist die Ausstellung des Zeugnisses nicht möglich, müssen Sie eine Befreiung beim Präsidenten des Oberlandesgerichts beantragen**.
> Wenn gleichgeschlechtliche Paare heiraten möchten und der Heimatstaat die gleichgeschlechtliche Ehe nicht vorsieht, muss kein Ehefähigkeitszeugnis vorgelegt werden.
>
> > Foreigners who want to get married in Germany also need a marriage certificate.
> > In this certificate, the competent home authority confirms that there are no legal obstacles to the marriage.
> > **If it is not possible to issue the certificate, you must apply for an exemption from the President of the Higher Regional Court**.
> > If same-sex couples wish to marry and the country of origin does not provide for same-sex marriage, no marriage certificate is required.

---

> [Oberlandesgericht Stuttgart - Ehefähigkeitsverfahren](https://oberlandesgericht-stuttgart.justiz-bw.de/pb/,Lde/Startseite/Service/Ehefaehigkeitsverfahren)
>
> - Allgemeine Hinweise (PDF 114 KB)
>
> **11. Kosten des Verfahrens / Einkommensnachweise**
> Die Gebühr für das Verfahren auf Befreiung von der Beibringung des Ehefähigkeitszeugnisses bestimmt sich nach Nr. 1330 der Anlage -Kostenverzeichnis- zu § 4 Absatz 1 des Justizverwaltungskostengesetzes (JVKostG) vom 23.07.2013 (BGBl I. S. 2586, 2655) und liegt zwischen 15,00 € und 305,00 €.
> Beim Oberlandesgericht – Verwaltungsabteilung – Stuttgart werden Gebühren aus dem Nettoeinkommen des ausländischen und somit zu befreienden Antragstellers berechnet. Stellen beide Brautleute einen Befreiungsantrag, werden für beide die Gebühren fällig. Es ist daher im Antragsvordruck das monatliche Nettoeinkommen des zu befreienden Teiles anzugeben bzw. ein entsprechender Einkommens-nachweis beizufügen. Ausländische Währungen sind in EUR umzurechnen.
> *Ohne die Eintragung des monatlichen    Nettoeinkommens des Antragstellers bzw. ohne die Beifügung entsprechender Einkommensnachweise muss das monatliche Nettoeinkommen jeweils geschätzt werden*. **Im Zweifel wird die Höchstgebühr von 305,00 EUR festgesetzt**.
>
> > The fee for the procedure for exemption from the provision of the certificate of unfitness to marry is determined according to No. 1330 of the Annex -List of costs- to § 4 paragraph 1 of the Judicial Administration Costs Act (JVKostG) of 23.07.2013 (BGBl I. S. 2586, 2655) and is between 15,  €00 and €305.00.
> > At the Higher Regional Court - Administrative Department - Stuttgart, fees are calculated from the net income of the foreign applicant who is therefore to be exempted.  If both bride and groom apply for an exemption, the fees are due for both.  Therefore, the monthly net income of the part to be exempted must be stated in the application form or a corresponding proof of income must be attached.  Foreign currencies are to be converted into EUR
> > *Without entering the applicant's monthly net income or without enclosing the relevant proof of income, the monthly net income must be estimated in each case*. **In case of doubt, the maximum fee of EUR 305.00 will be set**.

Comment: I live in Ba-Wü, and we were told that I would make a sworn statement (which I think has to be approved by the Oberlandesgericht) instead of providing proof of single status. This (the swearing) is part of what should be accomplished at our meeting with the Standesamt tomorrow. My main concern is whether a proof of income/earnings is actually required (in case they for whatever reason don't want to accept the way the Land issues payslips). ETA: I see now how the first statement is related. They need the income to do the swearing instead of me submitting a proof of single status. Thank you!

Comment: Take the 2 pay slips (one with the €300 and one without). Bank statements showing the 3 normal payments and the one showing the 300. They need proof of the **normal** earning. In the worst case you will have to pays the maximum of €305.

Comment: Please adapt the question adding the state and that you didn't have the required **Ehefähigkeitszeugnisse**. The last 2 sentances, I think, should be removed since they are speculative and as it as turned out compleatly wrong.